# Skip default parameters in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Is there any way to skip the default params, say suppose my method declaration is like this:

```
procedure MyProc1(var isAttr1: Boolean = FALSE;
    var isAttr2: Boolean = FALSE; var isAttr3: Boolean = FALSE);
```

I can't call the function like this:

```
Self.MyProc1( , , Attr3);
```

because I don't want unnecessary var declarations, at the same time I want the last param return value (it is a var type)

Thank for help in advance.

Comment: `var` parameters cannot have default values (of course!).

Comment: And the last param is not passed by `var`, only the first one is.

Comment: sorry for that I have edited the question

Comment: Er, you can't have default values for var parameters.

Comment: but the PaxEngine (Pax complier) allows me to do this, and off-course code behaves abnormally with this. Thought to avoid @David and @Andreas you are correct

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Sorry, you can't do this. What's more you can't have a `var` parameter with a default as you have with `isAttr1`.

If your parameters had sufficiently different parameter types, then you could use [overloaded methods](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Procedures_and_Functions#Overloading_Procedures_and_Functions) as an alternative to default parameters, which is a technique that I personally prefer. But your parameters are all Boolean and so you can't do that here.

Other posters have suggested something like this:

```
procedure Myfunc1(var isAttr1, isAttr2, isAttr3: Boolean); overload;
procedure Myfunc1(var isAttr3: Boolean); overload;
```

This will compile and work but would be counter to the principle of least surprise. For overloaded procedures like this, you would expect, for the procedure with only a single parameter, for that single parameter to be the first parameter of the procedure with multiple parameters.  In other words you would expect:

```
procedure Myfunc1(var isAttr1, isAttr2, isAttr3: Boolean); overload;
procedure Myfunc1(var isAttr1: Boolean); overload;
```

Answer (score 4):

In this case you should use the [overload](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Overload) directive:

> The Overload directive allows you to
>   have different versions of the same
>   named function or procedure with
>   different arguments.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, make an overloaded version of MyFunc1(isAttr3 : boolean = FALSE); overload;

Have it make up the dummy params and pass them for you.

As the other poster points out, you can do this with VAR.
Also, it's wrong to call it MyFunc if it's not a Function. Call it MyProc!

My solution:

```
function ov(p1 : boolean; p2 : boolean; p3 : boolean) : boolean; overload;
begin
  result := p1 or p2 or p3;
end;

function ov(p3 : boolean) : boolean; overload;
begin
  result :=  ov(false, false, p3);
end;
```

Now you can have your choice of:

ov(TestBool3)

or

ov(TestBool1, TestBool2, TestBool3)

Comment: But that won't work because of the ambiguity in the parameters - the other overload has 3 boolean parameters, all with default values.

Comment: I'd ditch the default values, and the var param and just make it a Function that returns a boolean.  I believe you can have two overloaded versions, one with one param, one with 3.

Comment: @Chris this is correct but has other issues, when treating the the question as posed; see the edit to my answer

Comment: I don't want to declare unnecessary variables because this will be rejected in the code review, the real concept is the (function--sorry) procedure will be called in three diff. scenarios and use these three var parameters accordingly, I can't write three overloaded functions again

Comment: @Vijay If you can't use 3 overloads and you can't have unused vars, then you it looks like you have to give up.

Comment: that's what :( @David, I will try another ways of writing this, thanks for all for your time

Comment: @Vijay you are allowed to update any answers that proved helpful and accept the best one

Comment: @Vijay: What David is trying to say is that you are free to *upvote* any good answer, and accept the best one.

Comment: @Andreas yeah, anyone would think that English wasn't my first language. Even why I manage to get the text in the right box (comment vs answer) it's often as not somewhat garbled!!

Comment: thanks @Chris your solution assisted me in solving another issue